# UITextField null from different class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the class

```
public ViewController1 (IntPtr handle) : base (handle){}
```

Inside the `ViewController1.designer.cs` I have registered a `UITextField`

```
[Outlet]
UIKit.UITextField _textField { get; set; }
```

Here's where I am struggling:

I have another class, `ViewController2` that inherits from `ViewController1`

```
public class ViewController2 : ViewController1
{
    public ViewController2 (IntPtr handle) : base (handle){}
}
```

Why is it that when inside `ViewController2` that my `_textField` is always **null** when debugging?

Answer (score 6):

Have you initialized `_textField`? Like `_textField = new UIKit.UITextField();`. Because all the fields are nulled when a class is created. After creating `ViewController1` or `ViewController2`, `_textField` is null, unless you assigned it something in the constructor.

More precisely, every field `T field` is intialized to `default(T)`, which, for reference types, is `null`.

Btw.: Your "field" is a property. But the same is true for auto-properties.

You could initialize `_textField` like this in the constructor:

```
public partial class ViewController1
{
    public ViewController1 (IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        _textField = new UIKit.UITextField();
    }
}
```

I must admit that I don't know xamarin. Do you have to call something like `InitializeComponent();` inside the constructor? Does `ViewController1.designer.cs` have a method called like this?

```
    public ViewController1 (IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In WinForms, for instance, the designer partial class has such a method, which creates the controls.

Comment: Would I be able to access what the user types in `_textField`? when in ViewController2 if I do that?

Comment: Using  `_textField = new UIKit.UITextField();` in the constructor of ViewController1 makes it so that it is empty and no longer null. So this fixes some part of it. But I would like to get the text value that the user entered in `ViewController2` Is this possible?

Comment: My second example with `InitializeComponent();` is probably better than the first. `InitializeComponent();` must be called in `Viewcontroller2` as well. Then you can get the text with `string text = _TextField.Text;`

Comment: It seems InitializeComponent() is not supported by Xamarin. Is there any other way?

Comment: As I said already, i am not a Xamarin guy. Have alook inside `ViewController1.designer.cs`. There must be some initializing method there.

Comment: @XamarinWarrior: were you able to find a solution to this? I am stuck with the same problem ;(

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have created binding for your Outlet field as specified in this tutorial?

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/controls/part_1_-_creating_user_interface_objects/

> Click on a user interface object; then Control Drag into the .h file. To Control Drag, hold down the control key then click and hold over the user interface object that you are creating the outlet (or action) for. Keep holding down the Control key while you drag into the header file. Finish dragging below the @interface definition. A blue line should appear with a caption Insert Outlet or Outlet Collection, as illustrated in the screenshot below.
>
> When you release the click you will be prompted to provide a name for the Outlet, which will be used to create a C# property that can be referenced in code:

Also you are not supposed to register anything Designer.cs, it should be generated automatically, if you did not follow steps of drag and drop and tried to add code in designer manually, it will not bind correctly.

iOS does not follow c# concepts, iOS only binds storeyboard objects defined in .h file included in the application. Though you are not adding .h file, but Xamarin creates it automatically and puts it inside application.